# geometric kernel in CAD

Tags: cgal, cad

I was wondering is it the geometric kernel that works behind the curtain in CAD programs when for example, we want to draw a line from a point to midpoint of another line ? does geometric kernel keeps track of points and finds intersections, perpendecular lines and etc in CAD software or there is some other part of software that handles these things ? I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

CGAL Kernel provides various geometric objects (triangles, points, segments, lines, planes,...) as well as operations on them (collinearity test, do-intersection test, intersection computation, ...).
All the object are discrete objects (but sphere and circle and maybe a few others) and there is no nurb patches for example.

I'm not sure I answered your question...

Comment: I want to develop an interface similar to cad for an application I am working on. I am looking at boost::geometry, cgal and opencascade. I am not sure which one is better. I am looking for functionality similar to autocad or QCAD.

Answer (score 0):

The choice depends on purposes and tasks of an application. For CAD geometry you can use [Opencascade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Cascade_Technology) technology. Opencascade has good documentation and tutorials. Also you can see [FreeCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCAD) system (opensource) that based on Opencascade as example.